# Loop animation inside the JS function

Tags: javascript, arrays, animation

There is a function that contains a local arrays and a loop
which somehow alters those arrays. Also function returns
one of arrays. Example below:

```
function myFunc(expr) {
    var array1 = [],
        array2 = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < expr.length; ++i) {
    // ...
    }

    return array2;
};
```

I need to draw on canvas an array with a DELAY after each loop step.

My first thought was to use a some sort of "sleep" function in the end of the loop, but Google said me that JS has not such type of functions. I not fully understand how works the "setInterval" function but as far as I know this will execute even when my external function (myFunc) will stopped and due to this external function will not returns "array2".

Comment: Yes, `setInterval` would be a good approach to your problem. Try looking up on JavaScript asynchronous functions, and then be more specific on what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the loop to "pause" while you perform some function with data avilable inside the loop and then perform a function. When you say "for each loop step" I assume it's for each step in the for loop.

```
function myFunc(expr) {
    var array1 = [],
        array2 = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < expr.length; ++i) {
       // ...
       // Perform something here after a certain time, while the loop waits.
    }

    return array2;
};
```

As far as I know, you won't be able to achieve this exactly, however, if you have the data available you can "fake" the behaviour you want.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udh0yqy9/2/) where I created an example.

```
function myFunc(expr) {
    var array1 = [],
        array2 = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < expr.length; ++i) {
       // ...
       setTimeout(function(){
           // Do whatever you want to do.
       }, i*500); // i = 0 is instantly, i = 1 is after 0.5s, i=2 is 1s, and so on...
    }

    return array2;
};
```

Your (estimated) timeline will then be as follows, from when the for loop is started.

```
0s   -> function in timeout when i = 0 is called
0.5s -> function in timeout when i = 1 is called
1.0s -> function in timeout when i = 2 is called
```

Note that timeout is not precise, and there can be deviations in the time before execution of the function.

Beware of scoping issues if you modify the variables you use inside the function, inside the loop.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Now I can not access to array's elements. expr[i] in function are undefined. [See on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/MViafv9x)

Comment: Because you have to use the variable you saved it to. See https://jsfiddle.net/x2vt8zye/1/